# Java/Linux/Docker 101: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/time/ZoneId

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to run a jar inside a docker.  I took the following steps:

1. sudo docker pull java
2. sudo docker run -i -t java /bin/bash
3. (In docker) curl -LO https://github.com/Netflix/atlas/releases/download/v1.4.1/atlas-1.4.1-standalone.jar
4. java -jar atlas-1.4.1-standalone.jar

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.netflix.atlas.webapi.ApiSettings$.newDbInstance(ApiSettings.scala:33)
        at com.netflix.atlas.webapi.Main$$anon$1.configure(Main.scala:29)
        at com.netflix.atlas.akka.WebServer.start(WebServer.scala:37)
        at com.netflix.atlas.webapi.Main$.main(Main.scala:33)
        at com.netflix.atlas.webapi.Main.main(Main.scala)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/time/ZoneId
        at com.netflix.atlas.core.db.StaticDatabase.<init>(StaticDatabase.scala:33)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.ZoneId
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.JarClassLoader.findClass(JarClassLoader.java:713)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.JarClassLoader.loadClass(JarClassLoader.java:630)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 16 more

root@17d3f6f54c1b:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
root@17d3f6f54c1b:/# echo $CLASSPATH
<not defined>
```

I believe the fix is painfully simple, I'm just not sure what it is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the `java.time.ZoneId` which was introduced in java 1.8.  Can you do `java -version` and `javac -version` on the Docker container and/or where you built it.

My guess is that you compiled on your local machine with java 1.8 and then pushed it to Docker with a lower version of java on the container.

Comment: JD, great info, I believe my docker has java 1.7. I will test out tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: Installing oracle 1.8 fixed the issue.  I installed it using the following:
```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer